# why instanceof does not work with Generic?

Tags: java, generics, typeerror, instanceof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Instanceof and Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics)

I am trying to write a function which cast a generic List to specific type List. Find the code below

```
public <T>List<T> castCollection(List srcList, Class<T> clas){
    List<T> list =new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object obj : srcList) {
       if(obj instanceof T){
            ...
       }
    }
    return list;
}
```

But `obj instanceof T` showing a compilation error -

> Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter T. Use instead its erasure Object >instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime.

any clarification or way to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: .. because you didn't search (-1); try `[java] generic instanceof` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570073/java-instanceof-and-generics , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768049/use-instanceof-in-a-generic-way , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741984/why-t-instanceof-t-is-not-allowed-where-t-is-a-type-parameter-and-t-is-a-varia?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397660/generics-and-instanceof-java?rq=1 (etc)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot do it this way. Fortunately, you already have a `Class<T>` argument so instead do

```
myClass.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())
```

This will return true if `obj` is of class `myClass` or subclass.

As @ILMTitan pointed out (thanks), you will need to check for `obj == null` to avoid a potential NullPointerException, or use `myClass.isInstance(obj)` instead.  Either does what you need.

Comment: That can cause a null pointer of obj is `null`. `isInstance()` will not cause the null pointer problem.

Comment: Also note that `isAssignableFrom()` returns true even if `obj` "can be converted to" `myClass`. Prefer `isInstance()` which returns true if obj "is an instance of the represented class (or of any of its subclasses)"

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: because a type parameter in Java is something just used by the compiler to grant type safety.

At runtime, type information about generic types is discarded because of type erasure but `instanceof` is a runtime check that needs a concrete type (not a type variable) to work.

Comment: Is there an `instanceof` analog for checking at compile-time? In my case, I'm trying to throw a `ClassCastException` as part of my definition of `Queue`'s `add` method. My first thought was `instanceof` but I got `error: illegal generic type for instanceof` during compilation.

Comment: @Ungeheuer You should bound your type variable.

Answer (score 4):

`T` is a parameterized type and exists for compilation purposes. It does not exist at runtime because of type erasure.

Therefore, `obj instanceof T` is not legal.

Answer (score 4):

Because java uses erasure, generic types can not be used to check against.

To get the desired result, use `Class.isInstance()`.

Answer (score 2):

Generic types will be [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) after compilation (generics are for compile time type safety) and will be replaced with most applicable type after compilation.

If you want make this compile, replace T with concrete type, example

```
obj instance String
```